# What are the differences between kivy.properties.Clock and kivy.clock.Clock?

Tags: python, kivy

Is there a difference between the Kivy Clock modules found at `kivy.properties.Clock` and `kivy.clock.Clock`? And if so, what are the pros and cons of each?

Every example I've seen uses `kivy.clock.Clock` and it has [documentation](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.clock.html?highlight=clock#module-kivy.clock). There doesn't seem to be documentation for `kivy.properties.Clock`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both classes are the same *at this time*.

[Clock is defined in `kivy/clock.py`](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/1.10.0/kivy/clock.py#L819). It is [imported in `kivy/properties.pyx`](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/tree/1.10.0/kivy/properties.pyx#L279).

Therefore `Clock` as a name is available in the module namespace.

So technically, it's possible to import it from `kivy.properties` but I won't advice that.

The maintainers may make a change to Clock that they intend to be isolated from the original Class definition and private.